# Ubuntu 20.04 boots to grub terminal following updates, unable to permanently fix with update-grub

Tags: grub2, 20.04

After an update Ubuntu 20.04 boots to the grub terminal. I was able to recover to the login by following the solution below, but each time I restart I get the grub terminal.

I followed instructions in this video https://youtu.be/r7meKJsjqfY to get me back up and running, but the last steps `update-grub` (I also tried `grub-mkconfig /boot/grub/grub.cfg`) do not permantly fix the problem. I get the grub terminal every restart.

My solution so far...

```
ls (hd1,gpt2)/ls (hd0,gpt2) <-----(this changes with/without external drive *)
set root=(hd1,gpt2)
linux /boot/vmlinuz root=/dev/sda2
initrd /boot/initrd.img
boot
```

(I've tried setting linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic and  linux /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic and using the respective IMG files)

After restart open the terminal. I've tried both....

`sudo update-grub`

and

`grub-mkconfig /boot/grub/grub.cfg`

which outputs...

```
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-42-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-42-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-40-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-40-generic
Adding boot menu entry for UEFI Firmware Settings
done
```

Do I need to do anything else? (I'm new to linux so the documentation and other solutions feel quite verbose and do not really describe my problem - at least I feel I'm close to a solution and missing the obvious)

Here are my grub files

`cat /etc/default/grub/`

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=640x480

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

`cat /etc/default/grub.d/init-select.cfg`

```
# Work around a bug in the obsolete init-select package which broke
# grub-mkconfig when init-select was removed but not purged.  This file does
# nothing and will be removed in a later release.
#
# See:
#   https://bugs.debian.org/858528
#   https://bugs.debian.org/863801
```

`lsb_release -a`

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal
```

- Additional info...

If I boot with and without my external drive when I `ls` in the grub terminal I see different labels for the root drive.

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,msdos3) (hd0,msdos2) (hd0,msdos1) (hd1) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (cd0)
```

Without external drive

```
(proc) (hd0) (hd0,gpt2) (hd0,gpt1) (cd0)
```

Comment: You have one MBR drive and one gpt drive? Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not older Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair & 
https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

Comment: @oldfred  thank you, the boot repair (option 2) worked..

Comment: @oldfred in answer to your question, the report showed 'no known boot loader is installed in the MBR... ```sudo gdisk -l /dev/sda``` shows I have the uefi system partition.

Comment: If UEFI, you should not have boot loader in MBR as all boot files are in ESP - efi system partition.  MBR exists with gpt only for one partition entry saying drive is gpt, so old partition tools do not try to repartition drive to MBR and damage it. MBR can be used for old BIOS boot, but should not be used if UEFI system.

Comment: @oldfred thank you for your help. If you want to paste your original comment to an answer, I will accept..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have one MBR drive and one gpt drive? UEFI should be gpt.

Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install, not older Boot-Repair ISO: Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

https://sourceforge.net/p/boot-repair/home/Home/

If UEFI, you should not have boot loader in MBR as all boot files are in ESP - efi system partition. MBR can be used for old BIOS boot, but should not be used if UEFI system.

MBR exists with gpt only for one partition entry saying drive is gpt, so old partition tools do not try to repartition drive to MBR and damage it.

Comment: Option2 worked perfectly... ```sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair && boot-repair``` many thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would try to recreate the initramfs with:

```
sudo update-initramfs -c -k 5.4.0-42-generic
```

Followed by `sudo update-grub` and a reboot.

Comment: Thank you for the prompt reply. Unfortunately, I still get the same problem. I've tried variations of your answer with the different images. Presumably I should always use 5.4.0-42-generic (the latest version)?